# Can not convert string to float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to get the GPU-Power from a  server .
This should be done  with nvidia-smi.

```
  def getGpuPower(self):
      splitedGpuPower = os.popen("nvidia-smi --query-gpu=power.draw --format=csv,noheader,nounits").read().replace("\n", ",").split(",")
      for x in range(4):
        self.gpuPower += float(splitedGpuPower[x])
      return self.gpuPower
```

I need a float number like 250,00

I actually get

```
(  File "test1.py", line 22, in getGpuPower
    self.gpuPower += float(splitedGpuPower[x])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:)
```

The output looks like this

```
$ nvidia-smi --query-gpu=power.draw --format=csv,noheader,nounits

8.50
7.43
11.04
```

Comment: Can you print `splitedGpuPower[x]` and check if it is actually a float?

Comment: Please show us the output of the `nvidia-smi --query-gpu=power.draw --format=csv,noheader,nounits` command.

Comment: Your string is empty, that's why you can't convert it to float: `float("")` is what you are actually doing here.

Comment: You need to iterate on `splitedGpuPower` without assuming a range, and skip empty strings, check my answer if it makes sense to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your output of `os.popen("nvidia-smi --query-gpu=power.draw --format=csv,noheader,nounits").read()` is `8.50\n7.43\n11.04`, the following should work.

```
def getGpuPower():
      #Split on newline
      splitedGpuPower = "8.50\n7.43\n11.04".split("\n")
      gpuPower = 0
      #Iterate through the list
      for power in splitedGpuPower:
          #If string is non empty, convert to float and add
          if power.strip() != '':
              gpuPower += float(power)
      print(gpuPower)
```

The output will be

```
getGpuPower()
#26.97
```